# On click get JSON data into DIV

Tags: php, jquery-ui, jquery

On click I am trying to get data from JSON via an URL into a `<div>`.

My JSON returns a single id and content I am trying to get content into div `#west-container`.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

My JSON Found at the url = `[{"id":"2","title":"Generic Overview","content":"This is content here"}]`

```
$('#jqxTree').bind('select', function (event) {
var loadPages = jQuery.parseJSON(
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'university/article/3', 
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json'
        }).responseText
    );

for(i=0; i < loadPages.length ; i++){
    var current = loadPages;
    $("#west-container").load(current.content);
}
});
```

Comment: why not use [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)?

Comment: why not to use success function of `$.ajax()`?

Comment: is this command jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'university/article/3', 
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json'
        }).responseText alone get you just this line?{"id":"2","title":"Generic Overview","content":"This is content here"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
 $('#jqxTree').bind('select', function (event) {
   jQuery.ajax({
       url: 'university/article/3',
       async: false,
       dataType: 'json',
       success:function(data){
           $.each(data, function(i, item){
               $("#west-container").html(item.content);
           });        //-----------------^^^^^^^^^^^^---This will fetch you the
       }              //--------------------------------content from json
   });                //-------------------------"content":"This is content here"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON( 'university/article/3', function(data) {
 // Do stuff here

 var oDiv = $( 'west-container' ).html( '' );

 for( var i in data ) {
  oDiv.append( data[i].content );
 }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "url",
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data:json,
        dataType:'text',
        async: false,
    }).done(function( data1 ) {
        data=jq.parseJSON(data1);
    });
```

in order to use the data, use "data.id, data.title" etc.

in order to push data to a div, use

```
$('#DivId').test(data.id);
```